# cobertura-maven-plugin 2.6 is used despite 2.7 is configured

Tags: maven, cobertura, maven-cobertura-plugin

I have this section in my POM:

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

When i invoke this command from terminal:

```
mvn clean cobertura:cobertura
```

`cobertura-maven-plugin` version **2.6** is used:

```
[INFO] >>> cobertura-maven-plugin:2.6:cobertura (default-cli) > [cobertura]test @ myproject >>>
```

If I add this section too:

```
<build>
    <!-- ... -->
    <plugins>
        <!-- ... -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Version **2.7** is used as intended. Is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example you've added Cobertura in version *2.7* only to reports generated during `site` phase. Goal `cobertura:cobertura` is [bound](http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/cobertura-mojo.html) to `test` phase, which is separate [lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference).

In order to solve such problems, there is `pluginManagement` [section](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin%5FManagement). Add the following to POM:

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.7</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

and everywhere else use Cobertura without providing version:

```
<build>
    <!-- ... -->
    <plugins>
        <!-- ... -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<!-- ... -->
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Comment: I see, thanks. And where 2.6 version is coming from? It is not in the super-POM, maybe defined in Maven itself?

Comment: Here are the logs:
```[DEBUG] Resolved plugin prefix cobertura to org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin from repository central.
[DEBUG] Resolving plugin version for org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin.
[DEBUG] Resolved plugin version for org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin to 2.6 from repository central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases).```
But I'm not sure why it fetches 2.6 by default from Maven Central.

Comment: `maven-metadata-central.xml` for cobertura plugin has `<latest>2.6</latest>` tag. Here is possible explanation: https://support.sonatype.com/entries/23778606-Why-are-the-latest-and-release-tags-in-maven-metadata-xml-not-being-updated-after-deploying-artifact

Comment: Here is the updated link for the [sonatype support article](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213464638-Why-are-the-latest-and-release-tags-in-maven-metadata-xml-not-being-updated-after-deploying-artifacts-)